# How can I pop last repeating item from the list in Groovy?

Tags: list, groovy

For example:

Given list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 4]

Choose element, which last duplicate will be removed: 4

Output list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8]

I tried that way, but it just removes first needed element from list:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 4]
def fruit = list.find { item -> item.equals(4)}
list.remove(fruit) //removes first matching item (one)
println list
```

I guess init(), last() or maybe toUnique() functions may be useful, but don't know, how to do this..

Comment: only if the last element is repeated?  or remove the latter repeated element?  ie, what should `[1,2,3,4,4,8,4,5]` look like?

Comment: last repeating of entered element, if entered 4: [1,2,3,4,4,8,5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this is what you mean, but:

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8, 4]

def toremove = 4

list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(toremove))

assert list == [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 8]
```